# AngularJS Best Practice: What's the best way to 'change templates' based on object data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Fair warning: Angular newbie here.

I'm using `ng-repeat` to loop through an array of objects and there at 4-5 different types of data in the array.

They all have the same basic format, but each type will have a few specific types of meta data associated with it.

Frankly, I'm not sure how to handle this without a lot of `ng-if` statements.

We're currently using Mustache with multiple template types (lots of duplicate code I hope to get rid of) but want to move into using Angular to handle this.

Here's a really dumbed down example of what my object might look like.

```
[{
  "title": "title1",
  "by": 1,
  "text": "First post EVER!"
},
{
  "title": "title2",
  "by": 12,
  "text": "2nd post",
  "meta_data": {
    "tag": 5,
    "img": "http://link.com/img.jpg"
  }
},
{
  "title": "title3",
  "by": 104,
  "text": "3rd",
  "meta_data": {
    "section": 22,
    "video": "http://link.com/img.jpg"
  }
}]
```

There's a lot more fields here, but I'm not sure what an appropriate way to handle this would be.

Maybe custom made directives like `<div activity-image />` and `<div activity-video />` that return nothing if it doesn't exist?

Thanks in advance for the help. I'm clueless as to what best practice for something like this would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ngInclude` to handle multi HTML templates and reduce duplicate code. First create a template for the common part of different template types, like below

`commonHeader.html`

```
<h1>{{obj.title2}}</h2>
<div>{{obj.text}}</div>
```

Then you can create templates as

```
<div ng-include="commonHeader.html""></div>
<div>depend on the type</div>
```

Finally in your ng-repeat loop, include different template according to the data type.